# How to random put the largest number in the set dataframe position?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random

How to random put the largest number in the set position? For example, in this table, the first three largest number in the column is 0.794242, 0.763451 and 0.755942  which was calculated from `df['Attack'].nlargest(3)`.

```py
# toy dataframe
d = {'Attack': [0.643,0.715,0.6826, 0.693, 0.7634, 0.7942, 0.745, 0.73, 0.755, 0.457, 0.634, 0.745]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['Attack'].nlargest(3)
```

[image]

Then, i want to put this three number in the first row(index 0), fifth row and ninth row in random, which is a regular cycle(+4). If the 1,5,9 row is not that largest number, then it needs to switch number. Then, one of the possibility might be this

[image]

How to do it? Thanks!!

Comment: Can you please provide your input in a reproducible format (text / DataFrame constructor)

Comment: the rest of the logic remains not fully clear, can you give more details ("regular cycle"? +4? …)

Comment: @mozway okay, I mean that the maximum number needs to be in the 0 index, 4 index and 8 index. so that it's 0+4=4 and 4+4=8. If i have more rows, the maximum number would be in the 12 index, 16 index...and so on. 
Does it answer your question? Thanks